# Generating http request in gaussian distribution

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I am using Jmeter for doing a load test on my REST API. So I would like to generate  gaussian distribution of request at a given time.

So from what I understand I have set my threads to 10, and ramp up period to 10. I have set the loop to 2. That means I will be sending 2 requests for every second.

But I would like to tweak this such that say for

- 1st - second: 3 requests
- 2nd - second: 5 requests
- 3rd - second: 9 requests

Comment: could you describe more precisely what you expect in terms of load ? Thanks

Comment: I am looking for generating say 100 users per second @UBIKLOADPACK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That means I will be sending 2 requests for every second.

that is not 100% true, it means that:

1. JMeter will add 1 thread each second for 10 seconds
2. Threads will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as fast as it can for 2 times
3. When there will be no more samplers to execute and loops to iterate the thread will be terminated

The actual number of requests per second will depend on 2 factors:

1. The number of Samplers (your test duration)
2. Your application response time

If you're looking for a flexible way of conducting X requests per second consider using combination of the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/), something like:

[image]

Both can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not correct, use this plugin to configure your rate:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/

On thread group set:

- iterations to infinite
- rampup to 1
- number of threads should follow the rule described here https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#How-Many-Threads-I-Need-To-Produce-Desired-RPS
- duration should be the duration of your test
- delay to 5 to give time to threads to get created

Answer (score 1):

JMeter will not be able to simulate the throughput with the Thread Group configuration (Number of Threads (users) , Ramp-up period and Loop Count).

To simulate throughputs you will have to use one of following components along-with suitable ThreadGroup configuration.

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
2. Plugin [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

Also most of the time JMeter will not be able to simulate the configured throughput soon after starting the test. Simulating the throughput depends on the number of available threads, server capability to handle the throughput etc